# node-mssql Transaction insert - Returning the inserted id..?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I'm using [`node-mssql`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) 3.2.0 and I need to `INSERT INTO` a table and return the id of the inserted record.

I can successfully use [`sql.Transaction()`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#transaction) to insert data, but the only parameters given to callbacks (`request.query()` and `transaction.commit()`) are:

```
const request = new sql.Request();
request.query('...', (err, recordset, affected) => {});

const transaction = new sql.Transaction();
transaction.commit((err) => {});
```

So `recordset` is `undefined` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements, and `affected` is the number of rows affected, in my case `1`.

Does anyone know a good way to obtain an inserted records id (just a primary key id) after a `transaction.commit()` using `node-mssql`..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of just doing an `INSERT INTO...` statement, you can add a `SELECT...` statement as well:

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;
```

The [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190315.aspx) function returns the inserted identity column, which means `recordset` now contains the `id`:

```
const request = new sql.Request();
request.query('...', (err, recordset, affected) => {});
```

I don't think `request.multiple = true;` is required, because although this includes multiple statements, only one of them is a `SELECT...` and so returns.

So the answer was SQL related and is not specific to [`node-mssql`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has accepted answer.
I made the following way:

```
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let insertItem = await pool.request()
    .input('ItemId',sql.NVarChar, 'itemId1234')
    .input('ItemDesc',sql.NVarChar, 'nice item')
    .query("insert into itemTable (Id, ItemId,ItemDesc) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID 
    values (NEWID(), @ItemId, @ItemDesc);
    var insertedItemId = insertItem.recordset[0].ID
```

This adds unique identifier to data that is saved to db (if table is created so)

```
create table itemTable(

       Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER primary key default NEWID(),
       ItemId nvarchar(25),
       ItemDesc nvarchar(25)
)
```